# Edit/Change 300 Multiple Choices on Server

Tags: apache

I edited all my server http status messages...
The 300 Multiple Choice is still showing up, when I'm typing in a wrong address, so it's showing me options.
Do you know how I can get rid of that? I don't want users to have a choice. Either I want to redirect to .index.html or I want to show an own created message page with a '>Go back!' option.
Server is apache...

I would appreciate some help :) (If there's a solution for my problem)

thx ahead!

Comment: Wow, I've never actually seen 300 before in real life.  Do you have [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html) enabled, and are you requesting a file that would fall under the rules defined there?

Comment: Thx for your comment...added "CheckSpelling off
Options -MultiViews" and now it's redirecting to my edited 404 page!

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your .htaccess file:

```
Options -MultiViews
CheckSpelling off
```

Comment: In my case, CheckSpelling off is sufficient, however I need to resolve how to handle the scenario of certain URLs coming with upper case and prevent giving a 404 message.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it a different way without using RewriteRules to fix this..

[image: MultipleChoices300 Error]

If you have index.html or `index.htm` as the first values in `DirectoryIndex` it will try to load those up first.. I put `index.php` as the first script to load up and the Multiple Choices 300 error went away. Although I never even had the Multiple Choices 300 error with my old configuration.. it has something to do with updating PHP to version `v5.4.16` or higher.