# "300 Multiple Choices" error due to htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, php-extension

I've recently been experiencing problems with my website which appear to be related to my .htaccess file.
The main issues are that some pages are redirecting to themselves, while others show a 300 Multiple Choices error page, which only ever has 1 page in the list.

The original setup of my .htaccess file was to both connect up my custom error pages, but also to remove the extension displayed at the end of each page (.e.g. /about.php would appear as /about).

Below is the contents of the current .htaccess file, along with a link to my site.

```
Options -Indexes
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L] 
# Added automatically by Gridhost panel Tuesday 29th of April 2014 07:12:58 PM
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 401 /401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 405 /405.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500.php
DirectoryIndex welcome.html index.html index.htm index.php
```

www.andrewcourtney.co.uk

I have contacted my website host regarding this, though they were not able to help and advised I post on a forum to find out what is wrong.

I've also adapted the htaccess file to the following but to no avail (checked within Incognito Mode):

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 401 /401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 405 /405.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500.php

DirectoryIndex welcome.html index.html index.htm index.php
```

Please could someone advise?

Cheers,

Andrew

EDIT:

I've now updated my htaccess to include the lines for MultiViews and CheckSpelling Off but now all pages just redirect back to the homepage?

```
Options -Indexes
Options -MultiViews
CheckSpelling off

#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteBase /

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L] 

# Added automatically by Gridhost panel Tuesday 29th of April 2014 07:12:58 PM
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 401 /401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 405 /405.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500.php

DirectoryIndex welcome.html index.html index.htm index.php
```

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13087356/edit-change-300-multiple-choices-on-server ?

Comment: Thanks Paul - I've edited my question to reflect the changes but as noted all my links now redirect back to the homepage?